# SSH login not working with TortoisePlink 1.7.11.3 + putty .061

Tags: tortoisesvn, putty, tortoisegit, pageant

I have installed TortoiseGit 1.7.11.3 and latest putty and ssh login configured.

I am able to ssh to remote machine without remote machine prompting for username and password.
But, when I do "git clone xyz@a.b.c:path destination" from command prompt, it prompts for the username and password.

I have set the environmental variables correctly for Git and TortoiseGit.

Could you please let me know is there an issue with TortoisePlink?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try latest TortoiseGit release. ATM: 1.7.14
Possibly fixed recently.

Comment: Thanks. It worked after an update. Sorry for the late reply :)